# include_path intermittently changing values: what could be the cause?

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, race-condition

We are experiencing a very strange issue across one of our hosting servers.

**The problem:** it seems like PHP's include_path is semi-randomly being altered by processes that I cannot currently determine. This is strange, because we disabled the opcode cache, restarted the server several times and have isolated user accounts from eachother by using mod_ruid2.

**The script that reproduces this problem (no content apart from this):**

```
// Removing this call from the file makes the errors go away
// This is just a part of our default include path, but is explicitly
// defined here to be able to reproduce the problem
set_include_path('.:/usr/local/share/php');

// Obviously, include_path should now be exactly the value as set above
echo 'Include path is: ';
var_dump(get_include_path());
echo '<br />';

// Debugging line: what is the cwd?
echo 'CWD IS: ';
var_dump(getcwd()) . '<br />';

// Test local file inclusion; this works
require_once 'bar.php';

// Test global file inclusion from include_path (location: /usr/local/share/php/)
// this intermittently fails
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
```

My current best guess is that some kind of race condition is being triggered.

**An exact description of what is happening:**

1. Call to set_include_path()
2. Call to get_include_path()

**Expected result:** 2 should match 1

**Actual, intermittent result:** 2 is empty or contains one of the following (at random)

1. PHP source code (docblocks)
2. Seemingly random strings, both long and short
3. Valid paths to other include_paths that seem to have been set by other users
4. An empty string
5. The string 'Content-type: text/html'

**We have tried the following:**

1. Recompile Apache and PHP with the newest PHP version
2. Recompile Apache and PHP with APC turned off
3. Clear the APC cache
4. Restart Apache
5. Restart the entire server

**Some technical details:**

- OS: CentOS 5.9
- Webserver: Apache 2.2.23
- PHP: 5.3.22

**Screenshots showing the strange content of my include_path variable:**

[image: PHP comments now suddenly in my include path]
PHP comments now suddenly in my include path

---

[image: HTTP headers now in include path]
HTTP headers now in include path

---

[image: Garbled content in the include path]
Garbled content in the include path

---

[image: More garbled content in the include path]
More garbled content in the include path

---

I am out of options and ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, that looks like a PHP bug.

Comment: You could try wrapping the call in a try catch and printing out the stack trace. Might help narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 1):

**This problem seems to have been solved now.** Since this specific server is a dedicated server running WHM/Cpanel, I have escalated this issue to Cpanel support.

After some research, the problem was narrowed down to the `homeloader.so` module, which makes per-user PEAR libraries possible. After disabling this module, the symptoms disappeared.

The root cause of this problem is still being investigated, but if anyone else is experiencing similar problems, this might be something to look at.